# I have a gridview which has multiple headers and Footer and i want to export it to excel shown in snapshot 2

Tags: testing, search

```
public void ExportGridToExcel(GridView Grd1,string Filename)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";
            string FileName = "FileName" + DateTime.Now + ".xls";
            StringWriter strwritter = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htmltextwrtter = new HtmlTextWriter(strwritter);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + Filename);
            Grd1.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
            Grd1.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;
            Grd1.RenderControl(htmltextwrtter);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(strwritter.ToString());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

After executing above code I getting output in excel format showing in snapshot.

[image: After executing above code I getting output showing in snapshot]

I need output in excel format with header caption and footer of below snapshot.

[image: I need output in excel format with header caption and footer as shown in snapshot]

Comment: You need to be clearer about the question you are asking.  Is it a styling question or a functionality one?  Tag the code language you are using in your tags too.

Comment: its functionality one